# How can I get 「req」 in my http file by using express

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller

I am using express to invoke api ~ 
Everying request go through: controller -> model -> http...

controller:

```
const model = require('./model');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    model.fn().then(data => {
        res.render... // res.send
    })
}
```

model:

```
const http = new require('./http'); // http module with get/post

const fn = () => {
    return http.get();
};

module.exports = {
    fn
}
```

http:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const Http = () => {...};

Http.prototype.get = ...

Http.prototype.post = ...

module.exports = Http;
```

Now, I want to get **req** in http... How can I do this in whole situation without passing param

Comment: You can't really.

Comment: Maybe, i can create Http instance for every router... @Molda ... but it's uncontrollable

Comment: Just pass the *req* or better just an object with options to the http that's all you need